# Can CallKit detect GSM calls and retrieve incoming number?

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I want to make an app which detects incoming and outgoing going GSM call.

The intent of this app is to send the analytics about the call to my web server.

I checked the CallKit but it did not give me a clear idea whether I could do this for GSM calls. It only talks about voip.

ACCEPTANCE CRITERIAS WHOULD BE

1. Detect incoming GSM call
2. Get the number of the call
3. At the end of the call send the number and the call duration to an API.

Same above for outgoing call.

I saw this code in CallDirectory extension in CallKit.

```
    private func addAllIdentificationPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {
        // Retrieve phone numbers to identify and their identification labels from data store. For optimal performance and memory usage when there are many phone numbers,
        // consider only loading a subset of numbers at a given time and using autorelease pool(s) to release objects allocated during each batch of numbers which are loaded.
        //
        // Numbers must be provided in numerically ascending order.
        let allPhoneNumbers: [CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber] = [ 1_877_555_5555, 1_888_555_5555 ]
        let labels = [ "Telemarketer", "Local business" ]

        for (phoneNumber, label) in zip(allPhoneNumbers, labels) {
            context.addIdentificationEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: phoneNumber, label: label)
        }
    }
```

Comment: No. That would be a privacy violation

Comment: But can it be done? It is for an enterprise distribution app

Comment: No, not even in an enterprise app. Possibly if you jailbreak the device

Comment: Then again what is addAllIdentificationPhoneNumbers does then ? I am very confused

Comment: That allows you to register names against phone numbers. iOS will then match those numbers and display the name your extension provides. Your extension never gets access to the actual incoming number https://pusher.com/tutorials/callkit-ios-part-1